# Add borders around pages through Nginx proxy server

Tags: html, css, nginx, proxy

We have an Nginx instance running as a proxy server, which redirects users to sites running on non-public facing servers, and would like to configure the proxy somehow to add a colored border to each page served by some (but not all) of the sites we proxy to. Can anyone think of a technique that would allow us to do this? We explicitly want to avoid having to change the application code for these sites to do this, and are looking for a solution that resides only on the proxy server, as we want to show the same site instance with different borders depending on the url that site is accessed from.

One idea that came to mind is if we could have some proxy servers modify a specific css file when it is served to the user, however we don't know how to handle something like this, or even if it's a good approach.

**Background:** this server proxies access to a number of different sites, some of these are qa instances and some are production instances. What we would like to do is:

- Add a blue border around all qa sites being proxied.
- Add a red border around all production sites when accessed through a specific sub-domain (which is used by our support team, to make them aware when they are working on a production instance).
- Have no border when a customer accesses a production site through their standard url.

Here is a sanitized version of our configuration:

```
# Customer production access - no borders
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name prod.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

# Support production access - target server same as above - red border
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name support.prod.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

# QA access - blue border
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name qa.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.200;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

And when a site is served with a border, we want it to appear something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to get this effect by:

- Adding elements to our base template to support drawing a border around the page (four empty `div` elements with the ids `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`.
- Adding a new stylesheet to our application - `border.css`, which is empty, and link to this from our base template.
- Adding two stylesheets - `border-support.css` and `border-qa.css`, which style the `div` elements to display a border around the page (the difference between these two stylesheets is they set the border to a different color).
- Adding rewrite rules to the Nginx server config which would rewrite the request for `border.css` to a different stylesheet whenever we wanted to apply a border to the page.

This does not 100% meet the goal of not modifying the application code, however it does mean that the choice of which border to display is entirely controlled by the Nginx configuration, which was the most important factor for us.

**border-support.css**

This, along with the border display technique, was taken from [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/body-border/)

```
#top, #bottom, #left, #right {
    background: #ff0000;
    position: fixed;
}
#left, #right {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 5px;
}
#left { left: 0; }
#right { right: 0; }

#top, #bottom {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 5px;
}
#top { top: 0; }
#bottom { bottom: 0; }
```

**nginx.conf**

There is probably some way we can clean up the configuration a bit to remove some duplication here, but this illustrates the approach.

```
# Customer production access - no borders
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name prod.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

# Support production access - target server same as above - red border
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name support.prod.example.com;

    location /static/css/border.css {
        rewrite /static/css/border.css http://$server_name/static/css/border-support.css break;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

# QA access - blue border
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name qa.example.com;

    location /static/css/border.css {
        rewrite /static/css/border.css http://$server_name/static/css/border-qa.css break;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.200;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your going to need Lua for this, this best way to get a start is in this forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openresty-en
Read up on Lua and what it can do, which is just about anything.

Comment: Thanks - can you name a specific feature of the framework that allows us to achieve what we're looking for?